# Trying to get property 'Ville' of non-object using Dropdown in laravel

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project and I'm trying to display a list which have the name of each country ('Ville') with their state ,

I am getting the following error when trying to get property 'Ville' of non-object ,

This is the form which the user select country and state :

```
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="from-box">
      <input type="text" class="search-field business" name="rech" value="" placeholder ="Cherchez..">
      <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="spec" id="s" value="spec" placeholder ="Spécialités">
         <option selected placeholder="spécialité"> </option>
         @foreach($sp as $ss)
         <option value=" {{$ss->Spécialité}}"> {{$ss->Spécialité}}</option>
         @endforeach
      </select>
      <select class="search-field location" name="region" id="region">
         <option selected> Région </option>
         @foreach($vi as $key =>$value)
         <option value="{{$key->Ville}}">{{$value}}</option>
         @endforeach
         <!-- nchoo ena sala7tha fel controlleur raw mech houni
            plus tout Hard Coditha fel controlkleur so warini l controlleur mta3 el rechefceh -->
      </select>
      <select type="text" class="search-field location" name="ville" id="ville" value ="Ville">
      </select>
      <button class="search-btn" type="submit" id="search"> Recherche </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

This is the ajax part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $('select[name="region"]').on('change',function(){
            var ville_id=$(this).val();
            if(ville_id){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/deleg/'+ville_id,
                    type:'GET' ,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        $('select[name="ville"]').empty();
                        $.each(data,function(key,value){
                            $('select[name="ville"]').append('<option value="'+value+'">'+ value +'</option>');

                        });

                    }

                })
            }else{
                $('select[name="ville"]').empty();

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And this is the controller :

```
public function index() {
  $articles = blog::orderBy('created_at', 'desc') - > paginate(3);
  $ville = vil::all() - > pluck('Ville', 'id');
  $specialité = spec::orderBy('id', 'desc') - > get();
  $pati = patient::orderBy('id', 'desc') - > get();
  $rdvvv = rendezvous::orderBy('id', 'desc') - > get();
  $docdoc = doc::orderBy('id', 'desc') - > get();
  return view('index', [
    'sp' => $specialité,
    'vi' => $ville,
    'pub' => $articles,
    'getpatient' => $rdvvv,
    'patient' => $pati,
    'doc' => $docdoc,
  ]);
}
```

How can I resolve his error?

Comment: `<option value="{{$key->Ville}}">{{$value}}</option>` In this line, `$key` is an integer, not an object. What does `$vi` contain?

Comment: `$vi` contain the table of country @TimLewis

Comment: Well yes, I figured that... I mean what specifically does `$vi` contain? Is it an array of objects? A `Collection` of `Country` records? (i.e. are these database records with a Model), etc etc.

Comment: `$vi` contain the name , id of country

Comment: You missed the "specifically" part of my comment... Is `$key` the `id` and `$value` the name? Or is `$key` the index, and `$value` the `Country` object? `{id: 1, name: 'example'}`? Can you just do a `dd($vi)` (inside your `Controller`) and add that to the question please?

Comment: okay sorry i just didn't understand your question, $key is the id of country , $value is the name of the Country

Comment: after runing `dd($vi)` display : 1 =>name of country @TimLewis

Comment: There we go :) So that means you simply need to do: `<option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>` to display `<option value="1">Example</option>`. Being aware of what each variable is (an integer vs an array vs an object) is the key to good programming and debugging.

Comment: i want to change the value="1" to value="Country_name"  , that's why i make $key->Ville

Comment: Or, why not `@foreach($vi as $country) <option value="{{ $country }}">{{ $country }}</option>` @endforeach`. If you don't need to use the ID, don't use it...

Comment: @TimLewis then the dropdown don't work :)

Comment: Well, you can't have it both ways... If you need the ID for the dropdown to work, then you need to use the ID inside `value="{{ ... }}"`...

Comment: can i make the dropdown with the name not with the id @TimLewis ?

Comment: That's a question for you, the developer, to figure out. The answer is "yes", you definitely can, but do you need to/should you? What's wrong with the ID approach? etc etc

Comment: @TimLewis well the list of country in admin panel (i'am using voyager don't appear with name , it's only show me the ID , because the value is a $key , that's why i'am trying to edit my code and make the dropdown list  with name of country not id

Comment: Please be sure to tag your question with all appropriate labels... `Voyager` (The Laravel Admin Dashboard) is not there, and definitely affects your question, in that I have never worked with Voyager, so I'm not sure of any of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="{{$value}}">{{$value}}</option>
```

change to

```
<option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
```

Comment: `$value` is not an object though.

Comment: in this case its an array. try $value['COUNTRY_ID'] .

Comment: No, it's neither... `$value` is a string representation of the country; it doesn't have any properties.

Comment: does this country has an id somewhere?

Comment: Read the comments... `foreach($vi as $key => $value)`. `$key` is the `id`, `value` is the `name`.

Comment: then just use         @foreach($vi as $key =>$value)
         <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>
         @endforeach

Comment: That's been stated in the comments as well... Might be worth reading through them.

Comment: u are getting an error, which tells u< that "$key" is not an object. Well, looks like u know it already.

Comment: Just remember, I didn't ask the question :P I'm sure the person who did knows that too (from the comments). There's a completely different issue here, but either way, this doesn't quite answer it.

Comment: honestly, i am confused in this case. i don't understand what needs to be done. Anything can be done pretty ez, i just need to understand EXACT task

Comment: That's what I'm saying... The question is unclear and likely can't be answered currently.